# Elasticsearch - search on index1/type2 document scores change when adding documents to /index1/type2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index (index1) in which I have one type (type1). I added documents to type1 and ran a search on it:

```
POST /index1/type1/_search

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "keyword": "quick brown fox"
    }
  }
}
```

I get a result set back with scores that generally range between .03 and 1.

Then I add another type (type2) to index1 and add some documents to it. When I run the exact same search again, I get the same documents back, but they all have different scores, now ranging from 2 and 5. Ideally, the scores of these documents would not change even after adding documents to type2.

Any ideas as to why this happening? I am running a search on type1, yet adding documents to type2 seems to influence the scoring of the results. Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

I am using v1.1.2 of elasticsearch. I should also mention, I'm working with a pretty small dataset (less than 1000 docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch scoring is detailed [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html), but basically what you are running into is that the inverse document frequency of some of your terms is changing based on what you are indexing into type2 (which is still in the same INDEX as type1).  The change in IDF changes the relevancy of your search terms.

The only way you could avoid it is to have separate indexes for type1 and type2 (and then if you need to search across both, your search would need to pass in both indexes).

The scores really have no deep meaning though and really should only be used as a relative indication that some results are better than others.